# How to put logo on navigation bar

Tags: html, css, layout, menu, navigation

I have 6 links on my navigation bar and did managed to attach a logo (which is a jpeg) into the bar, but instead my links are on top of the logo. How would I push my links apart so that my logo would stand alone.

HTML

```
    <html>
       <head>
       <title>TITLE HERE</title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       </head>

        <body>
    <a name="top"></a>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%">
    <tr><new class="right" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>

<!--Top Navigation Links (top horizontal navigation bar)-->
    <td id="nav1" colspan="2"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="LINK1.html" class="nav1">Name</a>
    <a href="LINK2.html">Name</a>
    <a href="LINK3.html" class="nav1">Name</a>
    <a href="LINK4.html">Name</a>
    <a href="LINK5.html" class="nav1">Name</a>
    </tr>
    <tr><td id="head" colspan="2"></td></tr>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <td id="main" valign="right">
```

AND CSS

```
td#nav1 {
height: 66px;
background: #000000 url('images/logo.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some padding to the left of `td#nav1` equal to or greater than the width of the logo.

Comment: yay, its a big day! 10k!

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as HTML `<img>` tag, inside `nav1` just before the home page link.

```
<img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="This is my sites logo">
```

Remove the CSS background property

`background: #000000 url('images/logo.jpg') no-repeat top left;`.

Add this to your style sheet.

```
td#nav1 * {
   float: left;
}
```

You can then use margins/padding css properties on the various elements to perfect your layout.